# What's the Type of value in React Context.Provider under the implementation of React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I did a chunk of code to use `useContext` and `useReducer` to achieve the local state management.

But some type errors poped up,

```
(property) state: Group
Type '{ state: Group; dispatch: Dispatch<Action>; }' is not assignable to type 'Group'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type 'Group'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(290, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<Group>'
```

To make the type `Group` to `any` will fix the problem and working well, but I don't really want to do that.

Here's the code:

```
interface People {
  name: string
  age: number
}

interface Group {
  a: People
  b: People
}

interface Action {
  type: string
  payload: number
}

// const myInitalState: Group = {
const myInitalState: any = {
  a: {
    name: 'Max',
    age: 16
  },
  b: {
    name: 'Pom',
    age: 22
  }
}

const myReducer = (state: Group, {type, payload}: Action) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'a_increase':
      return {...state, a: { ...state.a, age: payload + 1 }}
    case 'b_decrease':
      return {...state, b: { ...state.b, age: payload - 1 }}
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const MyContext = createContext(myInitalState)

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(myReducer, myInitalState)

const Comp = () => (
  // this state will cause type error, change myInitialState type to any will fix it
  <MyContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
    <div>Group</div>
           .
           .
           .
  </MyContext.Provider>
)
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It's because your context expected value of type `Group`:

```js
const MyContext = createContext(myInitalState); // myInitalState of Group type
```

But then you're trying to put something else there:

```js
  <MyContext.Provider value={{state, dispatch}}>
  /* here we have
  interface Something {
    state: Group,
    dispatch: Dispatch<Action>
  }
  */
```